# How do you give content pretty permalinks in Pakyow?

Tags: pakyow

By default, Pakyow has URLs like `/authors/1`.

How can I also/instead have URLs like `/authors/s-kyle-newman`?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should just treat `s-kyle-newman` as the ID (accessible via `params[:id]`).

Comment: It's not routing it out of the box, but the id is accessible. Now to get the Sequel query right (case-sensitive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Bryan, I figured it out and put it in a [blog post about pretty permalinks and canonical URLs](http://www.skylenewman.com/pakyow-pretty-permalinks/). If you've stumbled on this answer, I hope it helps.